# Access to NSArray from 3 different instances of class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

I have 3 different instances of a class and when a user taps a button (there are buttons for each of the instances) I want it to add the text of the button to the NSArray. But the NSArray must contain all 3 different sets of "historys"

Should I be using a singleton, or just keep a reference to the NSArray as a property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go either way.  I would create a singleton if I had more global data I need to share between the objects in my app.  If it's confined to only one property than I would probably just hold references to it wherever I needed to access it.